# EXIF "date" field is missing for Olympus RAW images

Tags: google-drive-api

I am putting together a little javascript to organize my pictures on Google Drive by date. I realized that Olympus RAW (.ORF) images are missing EXIF `date` field. Can I expect this to be fixed sometime soon?

```
"title": "PC010005.ORF",
"mimeType": "image/x-olympus-orf",
"fileSize": "14988121",
"imageMediaMetadata": {
    "width": 4640,
    "height": 3472,
    "cameraMake": "OLYMPUS",
    "cameraModel": "E-M5"
}
```

If I export it into JPEG format the `date` field is in there:

```
"title": "PC010007.jpg",
"mimeType": "image/jpeg",
"fileSize": "4710148",
"imageMediaMetadata": {
    "width": 4608,
    "height": 3456,
    "date": "2012:05:22 07:45:41",
    "cameraMake": "OLYMPUS IMAGING CORP.  ",
    "cameraModel": "E-M5            "
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for inconvenience. I raised a feature request for EXIF date field. Thank you for your report.

Comment: in the feature request plz mention the problem appears only for camera `RAW` files. JPEGs work perfectly fine. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, is there any way to find out when it will be fixed? It is a showstopper for me to store my entire photo libary on the google drive. Thank you!